# Retrieve children in a json using path

Tags: json, dart

I have this following json containing a sitemap data. I'm using this json for my navigation as well.

```
  {
        "home" : "home",
        "about" : "about",
        "contact" : "contact",
        "products" :
        {
            "home" : "home",
            "list" : "list",
            "product" :
            {
                "home" : "home",
                "specs" : "specs",
                "warranty" : "warranty",
                "related" : "related"
            }
        } }
```

Once the program is started, this json is stored in a variable like this

```
Future _loadData()
{
    return _http.get(url)
    .then((response){
        nav = response.data;
    });
}
```

Further I have a list/array to get the current page and the path

> List
>   ---- home>products>product

Now the user is in product page, I need the product's children to be displayed as the navigation links which are

- home
- specs
- warranty
- related

Three related questions:
How do I do this?
Is using json for storing and retrieving sitemap data a good idea?
Will xml suite this?

Answer (score 2):

At first you should convert it to a Dart data structure

```dart
import 'dart:convert' show JSON;

Map sitemap = JSON.decode(nav);
```

then you can investigate the `sitemap` variable in the debugger to see it's structure and access data in it like

```dart
print(sitemap['products']['product']['warranty']);
```

(should print `warranty`.

You also can iterate over the data

```dart
sitemap.keys.forEach((e) {
  print(e);
});
```

Comment: Without a decode, I'm able to print sitemap['products']['product']. My question is sitemap[ ][ ][ ]   <--- this number of square brackets changes dynamically. How to tackle it? Otherwise I can iterate over sitemap search for products, then assign products in a variable and then iterate over products and search for product and so on. Is there an easier way as simple as sitemap['products/product']?

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe make use of a recursive function like this (it could be optimized probably):

```
dynamic json_xpath(dynamic json, String path) {
  // Remove trailing '/'
  path = path.substring(1);
  // Get parts
  List<String> parts = path.split('/');
  // Return json if no parts, or we're at the end
  if(parts.length == 0 || parts.first == "") {
    return json;
  }
  // check if it is a map
  if(json is Map) {
    if(json.containsKey(parts.first)) {
      return json_xpath(json[parts.first], '/'+parts.skip(1).join('/'));
    } else {
      throw "Unknown part: ${parts.first}";
    }
  } else {
    throw "Unable to resolve path";
  }

  return null;
}
```

Usage like this:

```
Dynamic json = ...;
print(json_xpath(json, '/products/product'));
```

Regards,
Robert

Answer (score 0):

As Günter said, it is best to convert the json string to a map first. A function to get a map value from a path could be similar to this:

```
dynamic mapValueFromPath(Map map, String path) {
  List<String> parts = path.split('/');
  dynamic value = map;
  for (String part in parts) {
    if (value is Map) {
      value = value[part];
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
  return value;
}
```

Sample usage assuming json is the structure you proposed above:

```
Map map = JSON.decode(json);
expect(mapValueFromPath(map, 'products/product/warranty'), "warranty");
```